# What is better between OSM and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I would like to build an android app which will look a bit like google maps, and i was wondering what was the best between openlayers and open street maps? I know that open layers uses osm but I don't know which one is better and what are their differences.

Answer (score 2):

OpenStreetMap is a dataset. OpenLayer is a code library used to display datasets.

You can use OSM with any viewer (a GIS desktop app, OpenLayer or Leaflet etc). You can use any dataset with your viewer.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would you recommand osm with leaflet or osm with openlayers?

Comment: Leaflet is easier to use while OpenLayers has more features.